# Best method to detect a small moving object in an image, which can be partially covered (CNN/OpenCV)

Tags: image, tensorflow, opencv, object-detection, conv-neural-network

I want to find the best method to detect the position of a ball on a foosball table.
The ball can be covered partially by the players.
The algorithm should be fast, I would like to achieve 90fps.
The source of the stream would be a v4l2 device (/dev/video0).
I have only little experience with OpenCV and am not sure if this is the right tool for the task.

[image: Foosball table]

Comment: is the ball always white? I would try ViBe foreground extraction if the camera is stationary, combined with color and shape detectors as verifiers.

Comment: the best method would be to fix image acquisition. from that image you can't possibly get any useful data. try if IR illumination reflects off the ball differently vs. rest of the scene. those reflections are also a big issue. move lighting to the side, so no light reflects directly off the "green" at least.

Comment: The ball is white (some are yellow, but I need white to work as well). I will look into the ViBe paper.  Unfortunately changing the light source is no option.